# How to write a custom ParallelTable command that monitors progress automatically

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

I am using a lot of ParallelTable and want to avoid wrapping it in a Monitor call each time. Since each of the calls inside ParallelTable will already consume considerable time, I do not mind the overhead of the monitoring.

Here is what I tried (which isn't working):

```
monitoredParallelTable[expr_, {x_,xmin_,xmax_,xstep_}]:=Module[
    {counter,tmp},
    SetSharedVariable[counter];
    Monitor[
        tmp=ParallelTable[counter++;expr,{x,xmin,xmax,xstep}],
        Row[{ProgressIndicator[counter,{xmin,xmax}]}]];
    Return[tmp];
];
```

Comment: Try setting `counter` equal to zero in the `Module` initialization...

Comment: @kale try `ResourceFunction[“DynamicMap”]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a more complete answer to my comment above, *Mathematica* doesn't necessarily assume a variable is a number upon introduction. Initialize the `counter` variable equal to zero and then the increment will be handled correctly for the shared variable.

```
monitoredParallelTable[expr_, {x_,xmin_,xmax_,xstep_}]:=Module[{counter = 0,tmp},
SetSharedVariable[counter];
Monitor[
    tmp=ParallelTable[counter++;expr,{x,xmin,xmax,xstep}],
    ProgressIndicator[counter,{xmin,xmax}]]
]
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed solves the issue. Thanks. I think for the ProgressIndicator to work correctly it would be better to have counter*xstep + xmin.

Comment: @MrZ Sure, that would be the more general solution if your xstep is not equal to 1.

Answer (score 3):

This works for any table dimension. It also sends the $Assumptions to all parallel kernels (otherwise a simplification inside the parallel table will not be done properly).

```
MonitoredTimedParallelTable[expression_,indexesDescriptors__]:=Module[{tuplesLength,counter,printTemporaryCell,tableResult},
    tuplesLength=Length[Tuples[Map[Range[Rest[#]/.List->Sequence]&,{indexesDescriptors}]]];
    counter=0;
    SetSharedVariable[counter];
    printTemporaryCell=PrintTemporary[Dynamic[NumberForm[Clock[{0,Infinity}],{Infinity,1}],TrackedSymbols:>{},UpdateInterval->0.01]];
    With[{parallelKernelAssumptions=$Assumptions},ParallelEvaluate[$Assumptions=parallelKernelAssumptions]];
    tableResult=Monitor[ParallelTable[counter++;expression,indexesDescriptors],ToString[counter]<>"/"<>ToString[tuplesLength]];
    NotebookDelete[printTemporaryCell];
    tableResult
]
SetAttributes[MonitoredTimedParallelTable,HoldAll];
```

Comment: Very nice solution indeed. However, the HoldAll does slow down some of my computations drastically. I have not found a decent way around it except explicitly placing Evaluate@ in front of the mentionend expressions inside the `MonitoredTimedParallelTable` call. This however, seems a bit uncomfortable ^^.